# Magento 2 css and js not loading while transfered to new server

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2, forge

I have moved my magento to new nginx server ,frontend and backend css and javascript is not working. Have checked file permission everything is ok . Also have done static deploy,Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

If your js and css files are not loading, but you are sure that your files are in place (check it via ftp client) - check you nginx configuration. If you have changed the server, then it means, something isn't right with server configuration.

Magento 2 provides default nginx configuration with its source.
 1. Get source files of your current magento installation.
 2. There is a file named nginx.conf.sample (located in root).
 3. Apply it, restart nginx.
 4. That was the case for me for a few times.

Comment: I have moved magento to forge.laravel server .Before that it was running in Apache when i moved to nginx it was not working ,Should i change nginx config in magento root directory or in forge.laravel server

Comment: I'm not really a server guy (we have a guy for that), but as far as I know, when we had same issues - we were using wrong/outdated configuration, and after updating it to the right one (according to the m2 version) it started working like a charm :) 

For start you can try to change it in magento root directory :)

Comment: Get clean source of magento installation that is for the same version as your store (your store 2.2.1 so you need 2.2.1 source)
And look for nginx.conf.sample (located in root). 
I don't know anything more, like how to apply it for nginx or etc.